# Impact of Oracle 12c's Change in Definition of Significant Digits

Tags: oracle

In converting NLS_CHARACTERSET from JA16SJIS to AL32UTF8 in Oracle 12c, the number of bytes of characters increases, so I have tripled the number of significant digits defined for each column in VARCHAR2.　
I suppose that the increase in the number of character bytes will have an impact on DB performance, but will increasing the number of significant digits definitions have any impact on performance? (I wonder if there is any performance difference between doubling or tripling the number of significant digits.)

Comment: If you define your columns as say `varchar2(30 char)` then you don't need to change the size; if you define as `varchar2(30 byte)` then you might depending on content. The character set migration documentation has a section on [length semantics](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/nlspg/choosing-character-set.html#GUID-B3C74175-7F77-49A6-9CC9-1F6F70F3A69D). If you don't specify in the DDL, how is NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS set in your DB or session?

Comment: excuse me for my poor explanation, but i defined it as byte like "varchar2(30 byte)", so i thought i could affect DB.

Comment: Do you have a reason to define as byte? Defining as char is more flexible and avoids having to worry about this (at least until you get large values where you still hit the 4000 byte limit, which could be a lot less than 4000 multi-byte characters).

Comment: I am not sure the reason because its customers oracle DB, so I have to follow what they do.  Therefore, i would like to know increasing the number of significant digits definitions will have any impact on performance or not (I wonder if there is any performance difference between doubling or tripling the number of significant digits.)